# If $ a, b, c > 0 $, and $ a ^ 3 + b ^ 3 + c ^ 3 = 24 $, how to prove $ a + b + c \leq 6 $

Tags: inequality

If $ a, b, c > 0 $, and $ a ^ 3 + b ^ 3 + c ^ 3 = 24 $.
How to prove $ a + b + c \leq 6 $
I had tried some inequalities, like mean value inequality.I think it's a good way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$6-a-b-c=\sum_{cyc}(2-a)=\sum_{cyc}\left(2-a+\frac{1}{12}(a^3-8)\right)=\frac{1}{12}\sum_{cyc}(a-2)^2(a+4)\geq0.$$

Answer (score 1):

We have
$$
\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3} = 8\\
\sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3}} = 2
$$
By the [power mean inequality](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Power_Mean_Inequality) (also called the [generalized mean inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_mean#Generalized_mean_inequality)), we have
$$
2 = \sqrt[3]{\frac{a^3 + b^3 + c^3}{3}} \geq \frac{a+b+c}{3}
$$
and the desired result follows immediately.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Since $x^3$ is a convex function, [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality) says
$$
\left(\frac13(a+b+c)\right)^3\le\frac13\left(a^3+b^3+c^3\right)
$$